# xts operation returns NULL in candlesticks::CSPDoji()

Tags: r, xts

I'm trying to use the [candlesticks package](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=1317), but I get errors in some functions. For example, `CSPDoji`. Inside this function, `Hi(TS) - BodyHi` returns `NULL`. Both variables are xts, and the length and index are the same. Here is the detail:

```
library(candlesticks)
getSymbols("YHOO",src="google",from="2013-01-01")
head(YHOO)
debug(CSPDoji)
CSPDoji(YHOO)
```

When I step through the function `CSPdoji`, I got the following:

```
Browse[2]> n
debug: if (!is.OHLC(TS)) {
    stop("Price series must contain Open, High, Low and Close.")
}
Browse[2]>
debug: NULL
Browse[2]>
debug: BL <- abs(Cl(TS) - Op(TS))
Browse[2]>
debug: CL <- Hi(TS) - Lo(TS)
Browse[2]>
debug: BodyHi <- as.xts(apply(cbind(Op(TS), Cl(TS)), 1, max))
Browse[2]>
debug: BodyLo <- as.xts(apply(cbind(Op(TS), Cl(TS)), 1, min))
Browse[2]>
debug: Doji <- reclass(BL < CL * maxbodyCL, TS)
Browse[2]>
debug: DFDoji <- reclass(Doji & (Hi(TS) - BodyHi <= CL * maxshadowCL), TS)  
Browse[2]>
debug: GSDoji <- reclass(Doji & (BodyLo - Lo(TS) <= CL * maxshadowCL), TS)  
Browse[2]> DFDoji
     [,1]
Browse[2]> class(Hi(TS))
[1] "xts" "zoo"
Browse[2]> class(BodyHi)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
Browse[2]> Hi(TS) - BodyHi
Data:
numeric(0)

Index:
numeric(0)
Browse[2]> head(Hi(TS))
           YHOO.High
2013-01-02     20.32
2013-01-03     20.10
2013-01-04     19.95
2013-01-07     19.58
2013-01-08     19.68
2013-01-09     19.75
Browse[2]> head(BodyHi)
            [,1]
2013-01-02 20.20
2013-01-03 20.05
2013-01-04 19.86
2013-01-07 19.56
2013-01-08 19.66
2013-01-09 19.73
Browse[2]>  length(Hi(TS))
[1] 177
Browse[2]> length(BodyHi)
[1] 177
```

The result of `Hi(TS) - BodyHi` should be another xts. But it is `NULL` here. Am I missing anything?

Comment: You should send an email the maintainer of the package.

Answer (score 4):

I am the maintainer of this package. The problem is caused by a timezone issue when the timezone of the R session is not set to UTC. It can be solved with the command

`Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")`

at the start of the session. This is documented in the package-description (?candlesticks)

This is what causes the problem:

```
R --vanilla

Sys.setenv(TZ="CET")
require(candlesticks)
TS <- getSymbols("YHOO", src="google", auto.assign=FALSE)

#calculate the highest price of the candle's body
BodyHi <- as.xts(apply(cbind(Op(TS), Cl(TS)), 1, max))

# compare these two xts-objects
head(TS, n=2)
           YHOO.Open YHOO.High YHOO.Low YHOO.Close YHOO.Volume
2007-01-03     25.85     26.26    25.26      25.61    26654067
2007-01-04     25.64     26.92    25.52      26.85    32565729

head(BodyHi, n=2)
            [,1]
2007-01-03 25.85
2007-01-04 26.85

# looks good, but:
head(cbind(TS, BodyHi), n=4)
           YHOO.Open YHOO.High YHOO.Low YHOO.Close YHOO.Volume   ..2
2007-01-02        NA        NA       NA         NA          NA 25.85
2007-01-03     25.85     26.26    25.26      25.61    26654067    NA
2007-01-03        NA        NA       NA         NA          NA 26.85
2007-01-04     25.64     26.92    25.52      26.85    32565729    NA

# because:
head(index(TS), n=2)
[1] "2007-01-03" "2007-01-04"
head(index(BodyHi), n=2)
[1] "2007-01-03 CET" "2007-01-04 CET"
```

That's the reason the CSPDoji function fails. I haven't found a more elegant solution to that yet.

Comment: This is not a problem with `candlesticks`. It's caused by issues with xts. The first issue is [bug #2750](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2750&group_id=118&atid=516), which causes the logical comparison to drop the `tzone` attribute.  This has been fixed on R-Forge. The other issue is [bug #4904](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=4904&group_id=118&atid=516), where `reclass` doesn't copy the `tzone` attribute from the `match.to` object.

Comment: I spoke too soon. The `as.xts(apply(...))` calls do not preserve the `Date` index class, which causes issues. Replace those calls with `pmax(Op(TS),Cl(TS))` and `pmin(Op(TS),Cl(TS))` and the function will work without setting `TZ="UTC"` (assuming you're using the R-Forge version of xts with the #2750 bug fix).

Comment: Without looking, sometimes when `as.xts` is the problem, you can get around it by utilizing its `dateFormat` argument.  i.e. `as.xts(..., dateFormat="Date")`

Comment: Implemented Joshuas suggestion `pmax(...)` into 5 of the CSP functions, including `CSPDoji()`. It's on R-Forge revision 28. The issue persists in other functions like `CSPNLongWhiteCandles()`. GSee is right about the dateFormat="Date", but that makes the package unusable for intraday data. Still looking for a more accurate solution.

Comment: @wotuzu17 Maybe something along the lines of `as.xts(apply(...), dateFormat=indexClass(try.xts(TS))[1])`?

Comment: Thanks GSee, I implemented this into R-Forge revision 29 (candlesticks 0.2-4)